# Docker postgres java.io.EOFException: null when trying to connect

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I have my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml configured to start my two services - this is my postgres db and Spring Boot app.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
RUN export JAVA_HOME

COPY ./init.dump /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
RUN chmod 0755 /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.dump
COPY target/endlessblow-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /
COPY endless-blow-firebase.json /

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["java", "-jar", "endlessblow-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  endlessblowapp_container:
    build: .
    image: endlessblowapp
    container_name: endlessblowapp_container
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5430/endlessblow_db
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - endlessblowdb_container

  endlessblowdb_container:
    image: postgres:14-alpine
    container_name: endlessblowdb_container
    command: -c 'max_connections=250'
    ports:
      - "5430:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: endlessblow_db
      POSTGRES_USER: kuba
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
    volumes:
      - ./init.dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.dump
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5430/endlessblow_db
spring.datasource.username=kuba
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Now, the problem is once the containers are starting and db container is started, the container with Spring Boot app still fails to be started due to this exception:

```
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
            at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:455) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:553) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:168) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
            at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
            ... 57 common frames omitted

.
```

Here I am attaching full Spring Boot container log:

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.3)

2022-10-05 10:49:04.695  INFO 1 --- [           main] pl.jawegiel.Main                         : Starting Main v1.0-SNAPSHOT using Java 1.8.0_212 on f347c0966ca7 with PID 1 (/endlessblow-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /)
2022-10-05 10:49:04.699  INFO 1 --- [           main] pl.jawegiel.Main                         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-10-05 10:49:07.123  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-10-05 10:49:07.156  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 18 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-10-05 10:49:08.845  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2022-10-05 10:49:08.864  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2022-10-05 10:49:08.865  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.43]
2022-10-05 10:49:08.948  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-10-05 10:49:08.949  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4102 ms
2022-10-05 10:49:09.497  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-10-05 10:49:10.621 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:331) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:247) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-3.4.5.jar!/:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158) [spring-jdbc-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116) [spring-jdbc-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79) [spring-jdbc-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:330) [spring-jdbc-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.isEmbedded(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:182) [spring-boot-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.getDefaultDdlAuto(HibernateDefaultDdlAutoProvider.java:42) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.lambda$getVendorProperties$1(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:130) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateSettings.getDdlAuto(HibernateSettings.java:41) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineDdlAuto(HibernateProperties.java:136) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.getAdditionalProperties(HibernateProperties.java:102) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateProperties.determineHibernateProperties(HibernateProperties.java:94) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration.getVendorProperties(HibernateJpaConfiguration.java:132) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.entityManagerFactory(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:134) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1153) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:907) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:582) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar!/:5.3.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar!/:2.4.3]
        at pl.jawegiel.Main.main(Main.java:22) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_212]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[endlessblow-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:107) ~[endlessblow-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[endlessblow-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) ~[endlessblow-server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: null
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.receiveChar(PGStream.java:455) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:553) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:168) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar!/:42.5.0]
        ... 56 common frames omitted

2022-10-05 10:49:10.823  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2022-10-05 10:49:11.034  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.28.Final
2022-10-05 10:49:11.296  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2022-10-05 10:49:11.468  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2022-10-05 10:49:12.479 ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
```

What's interesting is that when I try to connect to postgres container on pgAdmin it connects correctly.

Comment: when you say pgAdmin connection works, do you mean you are connecting via `jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5430/endlessblow_db` url?

Comment: In pgAdmin I am just putting those connection values into specific fields I mean host, db, user and password. I am not putting this whole String anywhere here

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5430/endlessblow_db
```

this to

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://endlessblowdb_container:5432/endlessblow_db
```

Comment: Do I need to change something else or just this in application.properties? If just this then it does not work

Comment: and in your docker-compose: `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:postgresql://host.docker.internal:5430/endlessblow_db` change this too

Comment: If I also changed ports from 5430:5432 to 5432:5432 then I have another exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to endlessblowdb_container:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming for wrong database password

and application properties will be :

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/<database name>
spring.datasource.username=<database user name>
spring.datasource.password=<database password>
```

Dialect for postgresSQL :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Dialect for MySQL :

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation= true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Try this once.

Answer (score 0):

append below in your connection.
?gssEncMode=disable

Comment: This hint origin is https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/1871#issuecomment-694799547, right? If so, looks like this will work only for specific old driver versions around 42.2.15+